# How to write a rspec testing for hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

Trying to write rspec test for code below. The spec suppose to test that the right key is passed. Do I make a hash let variable and expect the key to equal the variable key. I am not really sure how to set it up.

```
def something_att
 Hash[
   %i(name age).map do |k| 
     [k, send(k)]     
   end
 ]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

first version something_att without parameters

```
it "test something_att" do
  hash_result = something_att
  expect(hash_result).to eq(
    name: 'john doe',
    age: 40
  )
end
```

second version something_att with parameters
(but you have to change how something_att methods)
I prefer to use this since it's more flexible to use with params you can set

```
it "test something_att" do
  hash_data = { name: 'john doe', age: 20 }
  hash_result = something_att(hash_data)
  expect(hash_result).to eq(
    name: 'john doe',
    age: 40
  )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, The spec supposes to test that the right key is passed.

```
describe "#something_att" do
  it "should have right keys" do
    expect(something_att.keys.sort).to eq ['name', 'age'].sort
  end
end
```